# request.post() não funciona corretamente gerando um redirecionamento 301 no Nginx

Tags: django, post, nginx, http-request

Estou com um problema quando uso `request.post('url', data)`, por algum motivo quando o servidor recebe essa requisição, ela redireciona (301) a requisição para a mesma url perdendo os dados do POST, finalizando como um método GET.

**Python:**

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://meusite.com/teste', data={'a': 'teste'})
>>> r.request.method
'GET'
>>> r.request.headers
{'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1'}
>>> r.request.body  # nao tem nada no body

>>> r.history  # analisando a historia do request é encontrado um redirecionamento 301
[<Response [301]>]
>>> history = r.history[0]
>>> history.request.method
'POST'
>>> history.request.headers
{'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1', 'Content-Length': '7'}
>>> history.request.body
'a=teste'
```

Como pode ver, ao mandar um POST, acontece um 301 (como está no `r.history`) redirecionando com um GET (perdendo os dados que haviam sido passado por POST).

**Log do Nginx:**

```
[01/Apr/2016:19:48:46 +0000] "POST /teste HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "python-requests/2.9.1"
[01/Apr/2016:19:48:46 +0000] "GET /teste/ HTTP/1.1" 200 66 "-" "python-requests/2.9.1"
```

Eu tentei enviar esses dados via `request.post()` tanto de localhost para o servidor destino, quanto através do próprio servidor destino para si mesmo e continua apresentando o mesmo problema.

O meu Nginx está configurado da seguinte maneira:

**Nginx:**

```
upstream hello_django_app_server {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/hello_django/sockfile/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name hello_django.com;
   client_max_body_size 4G;
   keepalive_timeout 5;

   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
       if (!-f $request_filename) {
           proxy_pass http://hello_django_app_server;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Ele está utilizando Gunicorn para servir o Django.

**Gunicorn:**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="hello_app"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/hello_django/hello             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=hello                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hello.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hello.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
view rawgunicorn_start.bash
```

O meu projeto está funcionando normalmente (inclusive estou seguindo este site como referência: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). Eu consigo enviar formulários internamente via POST sem problemas. Mas quando uso `requests.post()` não funciona, parece um problema do Nginx.

Estou precisando receber notificações do Amazon SNS, através de HTTP ele envia dados via POST e eu trato esses dados no meu servidor.

A minha instância EC2 está configurada tanto o inbound quando outbound para receber acesso de qualquer tipo (alltrafic), então não há problemas de acesso a instância.

Tudo indica que o problema está no Nginx ou ainda no Gunicorn, não sei.
Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após escrever detalhadamente a pergunta, consegui achar o problema. A URL do `requests.post()` tem que terminar com `\`, o fato de não estar terminando, está ocorrendo um redirecionamento para a mesma URL com barras no final, o que acaba perdendo os dados enviados via POST.

Após rodar o código gerou um erro 403 relacionado a permissão, que nada mais é do que a falta do `csrf` para o envio do POST, colocando o decorator `@csrf_exempt` (`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`) na view resolveu o problema.